# Add single CAAnimation to several CALayers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one animation, and I want it to be added to two layers:

```
[view1.layer addAnimation:theAnimation
                   forKey:@"layer1_animation"];
[view2.layer addAnimation:theAnimation
                   forKey:@"layer2_animation"];
```

But when I run my application, only the 1'st view is animating. As [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW14) tells, layer copies its animations:

> This object is copied by the render tree, not referenced. Therefore, subsequent modifications to the object are not propagated into the render tree.

So my code supposed to work correctly. Is it a bug or I'm doing it wrong?

**More code:**

```
CGFloat currentY = self.view1.layer.position.y;
CABasicAnimation *yAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
yAnimation.fromValue = @(currentY - 2.f);
yAnimation.toValue = @(currentY + 2.f);
yAnimation.duration = 5.0;
yAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
yAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
yAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
yAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;

[self.view1.layer addAnimation:yAnimation
                             forKey:@"view1_y_animation"];
[self.view2.layer addAnimation:yAnimation
                                          forKey:@"view2_y_animation"];
```

Comment: Could you show more of the code? What are these animations exactly?

Comment: Thanks! I added code and fixed the problem :) As you can see, I use currentY variable. As result view1 covers view2.

Comment: I thought that might be it. :) It is very unlikely that you'd want _exactly_ the same animation to apply to two different layers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my code. When initialised fromValue and toValue of the animation, I used y-position of view1. So view1 covered view2 and it was invisible.